# Trailing comma in object

Tags: javascript, trailing

```
$.ajax({
   url:"test.html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(html){
      $("#results").append(html);
   },
});
```

There is a trailing comma at the end of the last key value pair (success:function). I want to know that Does Internet Explorer trailing comma.
Code is working fine in google chrome and Mozilla Firefox.
But I am getting JavaScript error "Expected Identifier, String or Number" in some cases.
I want to know is the trailing comma is the reason for this error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Remove it and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with Ajax. It is entirely about the object literal:

```
{
  url:"test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#results").append(html);
  },
}
```

A trailing comma in an object literal was forbidden until ES5.

Internet Explorer does not support them until version 9 (and possibly only when the Doctype triggers Standards Mode).

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#Browser_compatibility)